# Make UL align center in parent DIV

Tags: css, html

```
.list{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:-20px;
}

.list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height : 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


<div style="text-align:center">
<ul class="list">
    <script>
        for (var i=0;i<60;i++)
        document.write("<li></li>");
    </script>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the UL center in the DIV.

Requirements:

- UL should be just large enough to hold the LI elems.
- LI elems should align left within the UL (either through float: left, text-align: left or otherwise)

Tried these but failed:

[Why won't my Div center itself in its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999398/why-wont-my-div-center-itself-in-its-parent)

[Centering an UL inside a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582922/centering-an-ul-inside-a-div)

[How to horizontally align ul to center of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946284/align-ul-to-center-of-div)

@mark's solution does not work:
[image: for Mark]

Comment: How about `.list { display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; }` and removing text-align center from parent? The 600px need to be adjusted accordingly to your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
text-align: left;
```

from `.list`

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/5Y5gc/1/)

Comment: If you want the list-items to be aligned to the left, why not use `.list li { text-align: left; }`? ;)

Comment: @LucasTan Have you even tried that with your own demo? Of course setting `text-align: left;` on a li will its content cause it to be aligned left. If not, there is another rule conflicting with this.

Comment: @LucasTan I don't get your point. You want to center the UL, but keep the LIs left? In your case you can't have both? How do you want that to look? You really should clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

by default, ul element is like a block, that means it will take 100% width of it's parent.
So if you want it to be center, you must set its width to a specific pixel or change the display attribute:

```
.list{display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your containing element has to have a width defined; you can't just say `text-align: center` for it to work.

Do this:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5gc/2/)

Essentially you're just defining a few properties on the containing element and took out the `margin-left: -20px`. in your code.